# jQuery use of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not very familliar with jQuery and it's functions. 
Does anyone know what these declarations are doing? (Btw. they wrap the entire .js content)

```
(function ($) { 'use strict' ... })(jQuery);

(function () { 'use strict' ... })();
```

The second I guess, is a declaration of an anonymus function to not make variables inside accessable from outside.

I know there's a ready function that is called when the DOM was loaded.

```
$(function () { 'use strict' ... });
```

Though I can't figure out what the first 2 functions do.

Comment: `(function() { ... }())` is the same as `function foo() {...}; (foo)()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are self-invoking functions, protecting the scope.

Note how the parameter (jQuery) is accepted as $ in the first function. In this way you can use the short-syntax everywhere, while still operating in a non-conflict mode.

Comment: Thanks alot, I guess I finally got it.

So if I'd use a global variable like this:

    var app = {};

and I put the self-invoking function below:

    (function(){ app.myString = ""; })();

the variable myString is put into app right after the script was loaded, and I can access it where ever I want ... right?

Answer (score 3):

```
(function ($) { 'use strict' ... })(jQuery);
```

This will make `$` available only in the scope of the self calling anonymous function, this means that `$` will not pollute the global scope and it will make sure that `$` is `jQuery`. If there were other frameworks setting their own `$` (like prototype), inside the function closure `$` will be `jQuery` because `jQuery` is the parameter passed in that will be named and available inside the function as `$`. Local scope variables in JavaScript have precedence over parent scope.

```
(function () { 'use strict' ... })();
```

This is a self calling anonymous function acting as a closure, usually to keep variables scoped locally and not leak them to the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function ($) { 'use strict' ... })(jQuery);
```

This one is used to make sure that $ in your code is jQuery. There might be cases with other libraries or code that $ gets overwritten. But this code ensures that $ is jQuery within the function scope.

So the function code in both cases is used to scope functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) { ... })(jQuery);
```

You can think this statement split to 2 part, `(function ($) { ... })` is to create an anonymous function, `(jQuery)` is call the anonymous function, this is similar to

```
function anonymous_function($) {
    ...
}
anonymous_function(jQuery);
```

some other library also will use the `$` (like [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/)), so passing `jQuery` to param `$` can be sure `$` refer to `jQuery`, and this anonymous function can create a safe scope for your statement.

And for `'use strict'` you can read more about it on: [What does “use strict” do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)